# Jmeter - Http script recorder getting error on recording

Tags: jmeter

In http script recorder i have done the set up which includes proxy set up to manual with same port on jmeter & web browser, added latest root certificate. Connection is done but the script is not recorded throwing error. Any suggestion will be helpful
[image: Getting error as below]

I have tried with updating port & reuploaded the root certificate, but its not worked. As per my knowledge done settings correctly but facing **ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install JMeter's MITM certificate into your browser, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it is being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

   See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry for more information

   It might be required to clear your browsing history like cookies, site and certificate data for the web site you're trying to record
2. It's better to use [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) (available from File - > Templates menu entry)

   [image]

   The Recording Template provides good configuration when it comes to transactions grouping, resources filtering, etc.
3. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
4. And last but not the least, there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.